# Neumann series theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A\in \mathcal{B}(E,F)$ "the space of bounded operators from E to F (both are Banach spaces)" such that $$\|A\|<1$$ We need to show that the sequence $(S_n)_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence where $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n A^k.$$
I see that if $p>q$  then $$\|S_p-S_q\| \leq \sum_{k=q+1}^p \|A\|^k$$ but how to proceed ?

Comment: If $E=F=\mathbb R$ can you conclude? Then remember what is a Banach space

Comment: @blamethelag Yes i know that if the sequence is a Cauchy one then it converges since $\mathcal{B}(E,F)$ is a Banach space,  I only need to prove that it is indeed a Cauchy sequence, I see that since $\|A\|<1$ then $\|A\|^k$ goes to 0 as $k$ goes to $\infty$, it seems naturel that it is a Cauchy sequence, but I want a rigorous proof.

Comment: In the control you have, let $p = \infty$ and discover that it's the remainder of a converging sequence, so that it goes to $0$ when $q$ is big.

Comment: Also, it is very standard that in Banach spaces a series converges as soon as it converges normally, and it is even a characterization of Banach spaces among normed spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the numeric series is geometric, you have
$$
\sum_{k=q+1}^p\|A\|^k=\frac{\|A\|^{q+1}-\|A\|^{p+1}}{1-\|A\|}.
$$
And because $\|A\|<1$, the right-hand-side can be made arbitrarily small when $p,q$ are sufficiently large. Which gives you that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy.